# Initialization of Singly Linked List with one Struct

Tags: go, struct, initialization, singly-linked-list

For an assignment I am working on, we were instructed to create two data structures that implement a Stack inferface (including push, pop, etc.. methods). While I completed the first structure, the Linked List portion has me at a loss. As someone who is writing their first Go project, I am unsure how to approach the following instruction:

1.Create a new struct called StackLinked that implements Stacker, and uses a singly (or doubly) linked list as its internal representation.

2.In addition to implementing all the methods in Stacker, write a makeStackLinked() function (not method!) with this header that returns a new empty stack using a linked list representation

Which I had attempted to implement as so:

```
type StackLinked struct{
    top *StackLinked 
    next *StackLinked
    data int
    size int
}

func makeStackLinked() Stacker {
    list := &StackLinked{
        top : nil,
        next : nil,
        data : 0,
        size : 0,
    }
    return list;
}
```

I feel I may be over complicating things (I have only worked with Singly Linked Lists in C++).

Does anyone have any suggestions or recommendations on the best way to implement the StackLinked struct and accompanying initialization function?

EDIT: The function header: func makeStackLinked() StackLinked {} is a requirement for the assignment and cannot be altered.

Thank you!

Comment: Why, the error is clear. Just change the return type to `*StackLinked` or remove the `&`. And for en empty struct, just `StackLinked{}` is enough.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have gotten rid of the &, that was a silly error. The main concern is the overcomplication.

Comment: @chrislamprey I thought the required signature is `func makeStackLinked() Stacker` where `Stacker` is an interface specified in your assignment.

Comment: @CeriseLimón That is correct! Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: In that case, you will want to return `&StackLinked{}`

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thank you. I have fixed that and removed the prev* as I don't believe it is necessary for this purpose..

Comment: Where exactly is the overcomplication? I cannot even see any complication at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
type stackElement struct {
    next *stackElement
    data int
}

type StackLinked struct {
    head *stackElement
    n    int
}

func makeStackLinked() Stacker {
    return &StackLinked{}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your help! I've got it all working now, I believe. Still similar to my initial implementation but it works so I can't complain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this following:

```
type Student struct {
    Name string     `json:"name"`
    ID string       `json:"id"`
    Next *Student   
}

func (s *Student) Insert(name, sid string) {
    st := &Student {
        Name: name,
        ID: sid,
        Next: s.Next,
    }
    s.Next = st
}

func (s *Student) Show() {
    for st := s.Next; st != nil; st = st.Next {
        fmt.Println(st.Name,st.ID)
    }
}

func main ( ) {

    root := new ( Student )
    root.Insert ( "Juan", "54542" )
    root.Insert ( "Lito", "93828" )

    root.Show()
}

Output:

Lito 93828
Juan 54542
```